# Couldn't run the iOS code

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, uitextfield, uilabel

Im a beginner in developing iOS applications. I'm following some tutorials. Simply trying to write UILabel's text into the UITextField's text, after pressing the UIButton. I've made the connections of UILabel and UITextField, to View Controller (on storyboard, in the left side yellow View Controller).
Tried many times even from different tutorials different examples; never works. (Tutorials Xcode versions are 4.0 though, I'm running Xcode 5.0.2)

Here is the .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *yazi;
    IBOutlet UITextField *sonuc;
}
-(IBAction)islem:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

Here is the .m File

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)islem: (UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *degiskenAdi=[yazi text];
    sonuc.text=degiskenAdi;
}

@end
```

Thank you for helping..

Comment: how are you setting the text in UILabel?

Comment: did you link your button with your function islem: ? If not, do this like you've done for label and textfield, except change from connexion outlet to connexion action. You can also put a breakpoint in your function (click in the small margin in the left, you'll have a blue arrow) if you app go here it will stop...

Comment: I haven't linked button action islem, now its working. thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi checked your code its working fine..

you have to check following in your code:

1) Check all IBOutlet are correctly linked.
2) Check your button action method is linked under 'Touchup Inside'(Check screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked :) So we need to link buttons action method. I googled it has some different ways doing.

Comment: ok you have to set button action 'touchup inside' for getting called function on touch button.. by the if this work then you can accept my answer by clicking Correct sign left to my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your IBOutlets are hooked up in the nib?

You should see something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1O5U.png

Comment: yes, actually i dragged and dropped (right clicked) both UILabel and UILabel IBOutlet's, on storyboard's view controller. so i saw stn like that and i did. except for the UIButton

Comment: In the case of the button, you need to hook up an IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

    @property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *yazi;
    @property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet UITextField *sonuc;
    -(IBAction)islem:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

Check that your outlet and action button is connected with .xib. This should do the work. :)